# Numpy create two arrays using fromiter simultaneously

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an iterator that looks something like the following

```
it = ((x, x**2) for x in range(20))
```

and what I want is two arrays. one of the `x`s and the other of the `x**2`s but I don't actually know the number of elements, and I can't convert from one entry to the other, so I couldn't build the first, and then build the second from the first.

If I had only one outcome with unknown size, I could use `np.fromiter` to have it dynamically allocate efficiently, e.g.

```
y = np.fromiter((x[0] for x in it), float)
```

with two I would hope I could do something like

```
ita, itb = itertools.tee(it)
y = np.fromiter((x[0] for x in ita), float)
y2 = np.fromiter((x[1] for x in itb), float)
```

but because the first call exhausts the iterator, I'd be better off doing

```
lst = list(it)
y = np.fromiter((x[0] for x in lst), float, len(lst))
y2 = np.fromiter((x[1] for x in lst), float, len(lst))
```

Because tee will be filling a deque the size of the whole list anyways. I'd love to avoid copying the iterator into a list before then copying it again into an array, but I can't think of a way to incrementally build an array without doing it entirely manually. In addition, `fromiter` seems to be written in c, so writing it in python would probably end up with no negligible difference over making a list first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.fromiter` to build one array with all the values, and then slice the array:

```
In [103]: it = ((x, x**2) for x in range(20))

In [104]: import itertools

In [105]: y = np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(it), dtype=float)

In [106]: y
Out[106]: 
array([   0.,    0.,    1.,    1.,    2.,    4.,    3.,    9.,    4.,
         16.,    5.,   25.,    6.,   36.,    7.,   49.,    8.,   64.,
          9.,   81.,   10.,  100.,   11.,  121.,   12.,  144.,   13.,
        169.,   14.,  196.,   15.,  225.,   16.,  256.,   17.,  289.,
         18.,  324.,   19.,  361.])

In [107]: y, y2 = y[::2], y[1::2]

In [108]: y
Out[108]: 
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
        11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.])

In [109]: y2
Out[109]: 
array([   0.,    1.,    4.,    9.,   16.,   25.,   36.,   49.,   64.,
         81.,  100.,  121.,  144.,  169.,  196.,  225.,  256.,  289.,
        324.,  361.])
```

The above manages to load the data from the iterator into arrays without the use of intermediate Python lists. The underlying data in the arrays is not contiguous, however. Many operations are faster on contiguous arrays:

```
In [19]: a = np.arange(10**6)

In [20]: y1 = a[::2]

In [21]: z1 = np.ascontiguousarray(y1)

In [24]: %timeit y1.sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 975 µs per loop

In [25]: %timeit z1.sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 464 µs per loop
```

So you may wish to make `y` and `y2` contiguous:

```
y = np.ascontiguousarray(y)
y2 = np.ascontiguousarray(y2)
```

Calling `np.ascontiguousarray` requires copying the non-contiguous data in `y`
and `y2` into new arrays. Unfortunately, I do not see a way to create `y` and
`y2` as contiguous arrays without copying.

---

Here is a benchmark comparing the use of an intermediate Python list to NumPy slices (with and without `ascontiguousarray`):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as IT

def using_intermediate_list(g):
    lst = list(g)
    y = np.fromiter((x[0] for x in lst), float, len(lst))
    y2 = np.fromiter((x[1] for x in lst), float, len(lst))
    return y, y2

def using_slices(g):
    y = np.fromiter(IT.chain.from_iterable(g), dtype=float)
    y, y2 = y[::2], y[1::2]
    return y, y2

def using_slices_contiguous(g):
    y = np.fromiter(IT.chain.from_iterable(g), dtype=float)
    y, y2 = y[::2], y[1::2]
    y = np.ascontiguousarray(y)
    y2 = np.ascontiguousarray(y2)
    return y, y2

def using_array(g):
    y = np.array(list(g))
    y, y2 = y[:, 0], y[:, 1]
    return y, y2
```

---

```
In [27]: %timeit using_intermediate_list(((x, x**2) for x in range(10**6)))
1 loops, best of 3: 376 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit using_slices(((x, x**2) for x in range(10**6)))
1 loops, best of 3: 220 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit using_slices_contiguous(((x, x**2) for x in range(10**6)))
1 loops, best of 3: 237 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit using_array(((x, x**2) for x in range(10**6)))
1 loops, best of 3: 707 ms per loop
```

Comment: Compared to `np.array([(x, x**2) for x in range(20)])`, this `chain` approach is 1.2x faster (1.5x for larger range).

Comment: Yeah, I considered this. It's probably not too bad because you're returning views into the larger array. However, I'm worried that because the entries will be more spaced out in ram, that the matrix operations I'm going to do after reading in the data are going to be less efficient. It's something that I should probably test.

Comment: Yes, the matrix operations would be slower on non-contiguous arrays. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to create contiguous arrays without copying. The above does avoid the use of intermediate Python lists, however.